# Items appear larger in Android Studio preview?

Tags: android, preview

So I'm designing my views in Android Studio and this happens:

http://puu.sh/it8CF/aaa697a7d2.jpg <-- How it looks in studio preview

http://puu.sh/it8Gk/047a18f276.jpg <-- How it looks in emulator view, of the exact same device being used for preview

This is making it impossible for me to design the UI for my app.  The icons are diffeerent that is intentional, but them overlapping is NOT by design at all. They are just supposed to be next to each other... My friend is running exact  same emulator/project from his computer and it looks like this in the Android Studio preview.

Here is a screenshot from his android preview:

http://puu.sh/it8OZ/4647e7a966.jpg

So where do I go from here, any idea on how to fix it?

As requested below here is the XML version in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/QxfBy6F9

There is a total of 20 icons in a Relative Layout, however this happens in all different layouts, not just relative.  I'm trying to code it to be a linear layout, with 4 icons per row, however the layout due to the size, if changed would put 3 and then cut 75% of the last icon off, even though on the phone it could show up to 5.

Comment: Can you post your xml layout?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QxfBy6F9  Here is the pastebin of it.  Its currently a relative layout. Trying to make it into a linear layout, but until I can get the views to load correctly it wont work.

Edit: This is is happening on every layout, not just this one as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are some solutions you can try.

**1. Keep your layout as is and set width, height size for your image button using below code:**

```html
int screenWidth = ...; //Calculate your screen width
imageButton1.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth / 5;
imageButton1.getLayoutParams().height = screenWidth / 5;
```

You can calculate screen width using below code:

```html
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
   int width;
        
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
     WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
     Point size = new Point();
     display.getSize(size);
     width = size.x;
   } else {
     WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
     Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
     width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
   }

   return width;
}
```

**2. Chang your layout to LinearLayout for each row:**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#00BCD4">
 
  
   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
   </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
     <ImageButton
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       />
   </LinearLayout>
   
   // Add more LinearLayout here...
  
  
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See the thing is, the problem isn't that its appearing incorrectly on my phone, its just appearing incorrectly in Android Studio. So right now when I try and switch it to a linear layout like I want to, this happens.

http://puu.sh/itacp/4a6048ce4f.jpg

Only able to put 3 icons in before the design preview cuts off.

Comment: Yeah, but that makes them smaller on the phone screen as well. The issue is, preview mode, blows up all the icons and makes them larger than they actually are. So if resize all the icons in preview mode, so they all fit, when it shows on the screen its going to be way smaller than intended. This is an android studio preview rendering issue.

Comment: Yes, because the size of emulator is larger than phone size :)

Comment: This wouldn't make sense though that my friends emulator shows the correct size, without needing to resize every single icon.

Comment: If your app runs on different phones, I think we should resize views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80847/discussion-between-jordan-maurice-and-phuc-tran).